# Removing non-alphanumeric characters without removing international characters in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to remove non-alphanumeric character in a string, but not remove international characters, like accented letters. I also want to keep whitespace. Here is what I have so far:

```
the_string = the_string.gsub(/[^a-z0-9 -]/i, '')
```

This does remove international accented alpha characters though.

**Solution that I used:**

```
the_string = the_string.gsub(/[^\p{Alnum}\p{Space}-]/u, '')
```

It works! Thanks.

Comment: Using ruby version: ruby 1.9.3p194

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [character properties](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties) to do this:

```
the_string.gsub(/[^\p{Alnum} -]/, '')
```

You may also want to use `\p{Space}` to keep other whitespace such as non-breaking spaces etc.:

```
the_string.gsub(/[^\p{Alnum}\p{Space}-]/, '')
```

(This also keeps the `-` character, which you have in your regexp.)

Comment: Using your second example, I get this error: incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)

Comment: @KevinM Try adding the `u` flag to specify the regex is utf-8: `/[^\p{Alnum}\p{Space}-]/u`.

Comment: This modifier doesn't exist in Ruby.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte which modifier, `u`? “Regular expressions are assumed to use the source encoding. This can be overridden with one of the following modifiers. `/pat/u` - UTF-8” – http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Encoding

Comment: You are right, I didn't know that these modifiers was available in Ruby. Thanks for the information.